# Automatically update from subversion using SmartSVN

Tags: svn, smartsvn

anybody know how can i automatically get updates from subversion copy using SmartSvn. Im using MAC. or any alternative SVN who can do automatically updates when subversion has a new committed file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that SmartSVN or any SVN-client have a feature of a hook that listen to a commit event and trigger an update.
You can try writing a script with cron (or using a tool such as Jenkins) that listen to such events (or testing the changes every few minutes) and performs an update for such cases.

BTW, I've switched to work with 'Versions' tool (https://versionsapp.com/) on my macbook after using SmartSVN for a while.

Comment: in Svn Tortoise they had an automatically command and I used that & work fine, but my problem is tortoise has no support for MAC so I switch some SVN for MAC. BTW, thanks for your answer.